# How to keep a link disable when it's still on the same page

Tags: html

I am newbie on web development.

How to keep a link disable when it's still on the same page.

this is my code

```
     <a id="myb"class="navbar-brand scroll-top" href="#" onClick="parent.location='../index.php'">Pangitaa</a>
```

when i click on this link i can go back to my home. but when i click it twice it will go out from my folder project.

i am using onClick function also because href wont work. I hope someone can help me. Thanks

Comment: if($_SERVER['SERVER_NAME']=="www.youdomain.com"){  <a id="myb"class="navbar-brand scroll-top" href="#">Pangitaa</a>}else{ <a id="myb"class="navbar-brand scroll-top" href="#" onClick="parent.location='../index.php'">Pangitaa</a>}

Comment: thanks but is there anyway i can do it in jquery ?

Comment: var url      = window.location.href;  if(url!="www.youdomain.com.index.php"){<a id="myb"class="navbar-brand scroll-top" href="#" onClick="parent.location='../index.php'">Pangitaa</a>}else{<a id="myb"class="navbar-brand scroll-top" href="#">Pangitaa</a>}

Comment: im working on it. thanks ! hope it works

Comment: wait. Im having problem where I can insert the statement you gave ?

should i put it on a function ? or insert this inside my html div ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
        <div id="brand">  </div>

        <script>    
        var url = window.location.href;             
        if(url!="http://localhost:8080/pangitaa/index.php"){
            $("#brand").html('<a id="logo"class="navbar-brand scroll-top"></a> <a id="myb"class="navbar-brand scroll-top" href="#" onClick="parent.location=\'../index.php\'">Pangitaa</a>');
        }else{
            $("#brand").html('<a id="logo"class="navbar-brand scroll-top"></a> <a id="myb"class="navbar-brand scroll-top" href="#">Pangitaa</a>')
        }

        </script>
```

Comment: thanks for helping. but it doesn't work. it duplicate my two link and already change the url in the if statement

Comment: <div id="brand">
            <a id="logo"class="navbar-brand scroll-top"></a>
            <a id="myb"class="navbar-brand scroll-top" href="#" onClick="parent.location='../index.php'">Pangitaa</a>
           </div>

this is my code inside my div. 

http://localhost:8080/pangitaa/index.php this is also my url in my home

Comment: thanks sir. it worked ! but i have a question how can I change my url if i want to base it on my root directory

Comment: i didnt get you. cany you brief?

Comment: i mean in this if(url!="http://localhost:8080/pangitaa/index.php") code. how can i change it. what if i am gonna upload my website. is there anyway i can do like this  if(../index.php")  ?

Comment: you can check the current url console.log(url); you can see in browser console